# Failed compiling of RInside examples in Linux

Tags: c++, r, rinside

I'm trying to use RInside with the standard examples in the package on Ubuntu. I just used make command in the source of RInside after installed it.

The Information about my OS: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1), GNU Make 3.81, R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) , RInside 0.2.11 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is the compilation errors. Can anyone help me ? : )

```
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include -O3 -pipe -g -Wall    rinside_module_sample0.cpp  -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR  -lblas -llapack  -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib -o rinside_module_sample0
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:64:0,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include/RInsideCommon.h:38,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include/RInside.h:26,
             from rinside_module_sample0.cpp:7:
rinside_module_sample0.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Module.h:451:5: error: ‘Shield’ was not declared in this scope
 Shield<SEXP> __load_module_call__( Rf_lang2( GET_MODULE_SYM, _rcpp_module_boot_##NAME() ); \
 ^
rinside_module_sample0.cpp:27:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_RCPP_MODULE’
 R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling) ;
              ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Module.h:451:5: note: suggested alternative:
 Shield<SEXP> __load_module_call__( Rf_lang2( GET_MODULE_SYM, _rcpp_module_boot_##NAME() ); \
 ^
rinside_module_sample0.cpp:27:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_RCPP_MODULE’
 R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling) ;
              ^
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/protection/protection.h:21:0,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:129,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include/RInsideCommon.h:38,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include/RInside.h:26,
             from rinside_module_sample0.cpp:7:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/protection/Shield.h:29:11: note:   ‘Rcpp::Shield’
 class Shield{
       ^
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:64:0,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include/RInsideCommon.h:38,
             from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include/RInside.h:26,
             from rinside_module_sample0.cpp:7:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Module.h:451:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
 Shield<SEXP> __load_module_call__( Rf_lang2( GET_MODULE_SYM, _rcpp_module_boot_##NAME() ); \
            ^
rinside_module_sample0.cpp:27:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_RCPP_MODULE’
 R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling) ;
              ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Module.h:451:94: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
 Shield<SEXP> __load_module_call__( Rf_lang2( GET_MODULE_SYM, _rcpp_module_boot_##NAME() ); \
                                                                                          ^
rinside_module_sample0.cpp:27:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_RCPP_MODULE’
 R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling) ;
              ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Module.h:452:13: error: ‘__load_module_call__’ was not declared in this scope
 Rf_eval(__load_module_call__), R_GlobalEnv );
         ^
rinside_module_sample0.cpp:27:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_RCPP_MODULE’
 R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling) ;
              ^
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Module.h:452:48: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
 Rf_eval(__load_module_call__), R_GlobalEnv );
                                            ^
rinside_module_sample0.cpp:27:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_RCPP_MODULE’
 R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling) ;
              ^
make: *** [rinside_module_sample0] Error 1
```

Comment: You need to give us some more information than just a dump of compile errors. What versions of RInside and Ununtu are you working with? What versions of Make and GCC are you using? Have you taken any steps to try to fix the failed compilation before coming here, and what were the results of those steps?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm relatively new in programming. I think that I ask the question in a wrong way. The Information about my OS: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1), GNU Make 3.81, R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) , RInside 0.2.11 and Ubuntu 14.04. I have only installed and uninstalled the RIside packages many times. I also tried to put them in different paths. But it did not work. Because of my limited knowledge in programming I really do not know what to do now. Hope this time my question is better aksed

Comment: That is pretty excessive downvoting.  It is a fair question, and reasonably clearly posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question did not show **how** you launched the compilation.  RInside depends on both R and Rcpp, and therefore uses a moderately complex Makefile.  But *if you just that* things should work.  On my Ubuntu 14.04 system, and using the code in the git repo for RInside which gets installed with the package you get from CRAN:

```
edd@max:~$ cd git/rinside/inst/examples/standard/
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard$ make rinside_sample0
g++-4.8 -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include \
 -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include -g -O2 -fstack-protector \
 --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 \
 -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -Wall   \
  rinside_sample0.cpp  -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib/R/lib \
  -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm  -lblas -llapack  \
  -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib \
  -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib \
   -o rinside_sample0
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard$ ./rinside_sample0 
Hello, world!
edd@max:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard$
```

This is pretty verbose since I changed the Debian/Ubuntu package of R to reflect many of
the default hardening flags, plus we need headers and libraries for several things.

But the main thing is: just say `make` in the examples directory and everything should build.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks so much for your answer. I just stayed in the RInside/examples/standard directory and say make in the terminal. I think that I do all the things following the standard steps. But it seems the compilation still does not work. In addition, I get the R by calling apt-get install. Is there a problem with my R ?

Comment: Your R version is likely fine, but maybe your Rcpp version needs an update.  Try reinstalling Rcpp from CRAN, then reinstall RInside, then try the examples.